# Issue with .htaccess redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am trying to run a bunch of 301 redirects using an .htaccess file. However my rules are not working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my rules:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /directory/1 http://www.example.org/newdirectory
RedirectMatch 301 /anotherdirectory/2/3 http://www.example.org/newdirectory
```

If I visit [www.example.org/directory](http://www.example.org) I get redirected to the correct place. However if I visit [www.example.org/directory/1](http://www.example.org) I do not get redirected. It seems to only work when there is just 1 level if I try to add more levels it stops working

Is there an issue with using "/" in the match? Should I try a regex expression instead of the actual path?

Please anyone can shed some light on this?

Comment: No it's in the the root

Comment: There is no directive to redirect `/directory` alone, so there must be something else.

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out.. there is a "space" in the name that when it's represented in the browser is encoded to %20 however I think that when it's requested it's actually a " " so in that case it doesn't match. I don't think it has to do with the "/"

Comment: Here is the actual rule that's causing the problem 

RedirectMatch 301 /engagement-rings/settingtype-MICRO%20PAVE/advanced-true https://www.gabrielny.com/engagement-rings/pave-engagement-rings